# How can i move images on touch event?

Tags: iphone

I have created a image gallery. I show all images from plist file in navigation view. When i open image in full view after that i have to back in navigation. But i want to move images in scrolling when image in fullview. After open image in full view i want to swap one by one next as well as previous...
Is there possible..??
Plz give me help about any kind..
Regards....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes thats possible, make your fullview a scrollview with its contentsize having the same width as your screen and its height being the combined height of its subviews (put at least two or 3 imageviews in the scrollview as subviews). You can add and remove UIImageviews as subviews of the uiscrollview as the user vertically pages through them.  You will need to communicate with the navigation view what the table status is when your user returns to that view though so that everything matches up.